# Asp.Net identity sample project with web api , especially the asp.net identity 2.0-beta

Tags: asp.net-identity

Does Asp.Net identity 2.0-beta has an example on how to use it in web api project? I have seen a sample project with asp.net mvc, but would like to see an example with asp.net web api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api) uses it in a Web API application.

```
This tutorial shows how to authenticate a web API using individual user 
accounts that are managed in a local database. 

...This method uses ASP.NET Identity to add the user to the database.
```

Comment: I see, do you know this still applies to the asp.net identity 2.0-beta, which seems a big change with the original version.

Comment: I haven't tried yet but it should do sooner or later. Here explains how to update it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx

Comment: i see, I hope asp.net identity team could provide a sample project on asp.net identity 2.0. I see they have a sample NuGet project on asp.net mvc, but would love to see a similar project on Asp.Net web api